# PHP contact form not working?

Tags: php, html

First i want to start by saying this is my first time with PHP outside of reading.

I am just trying to create a simple contact form that will gather the information and send me the email with the information. Currently my contact page is down and any help would be awesome to get it back up.

Here is my Code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
if(!empty($_POST['CompanyName'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['Email']){
        $CompanyName = $_POST['CompanyName'];
        $PhoneNumber = $_POST['PhoneNumber'];
        $Email = $_POST['Email'];
        $IndustryType = $_POST['IndustryType'];
        $Website = $_POST['Website'];
        $Other = $_POST['Other'];
        $Comments =$_POST['comments'];
        $formcontent ="From: $CompanyName \n Message: \n Point of Contact: $NameInput \n Email: $Email \n Industry: $IndustryType $Other \n Website: $Website \n  Comments: $Comments";
        $recipient = "keeano@doodleinc.co"; 
        $subject = "Website Contact\ $IndustryType";
        $mailHeader = "From $Email \r\n";
        echo '<p class="collapse">Thank you for contacting <font color="#709900">Doodle Inc.</font>, someone will contact you within 48 hours.</p>';
        mail($Email, $subject, $formcontent);

    }
    else {
        echo 'Please Check required fields with an <font color="#FF0000">*      </font>.\n If you are exsperiancing any technical issues or have not heard back from us   please contact us at <a href="">Techsupport@doodleinc.co</a>';
    }
}
}?>

    <div class="article">
      <h2><span>send us an</span> email ...</h2><div class="clr"></div>
    <form name="contact_form" method="post" action="mail.php" onSubmit="return    evalid()">
<table border="0">
<tbody class="Form">
<tr>
<td>
<label for="NameInput">Your Name:<font color="#FF0000">*</font></label>
<input id="NameInput" name="NameInput"/>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <label for="CompanyName">Your Company:<font color="#FF0000">*</font></label>
 <input id="CompanyName" name="CompanyName"/>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td>
<label id="PhoneNumber" name="PhoneNumber">Phone: </label>
 <input id="PhoneNumber" name="PhoneNumber"/>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <label id="Email" name="Email">Email:<font color="#FF0000">*</font></label>
 <input id="Email" name="Email" type="email"/>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <label for="Website">Website: </label>
 <input id="Website" name="Website"/>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <label for="IndustryType" name="IndustryType">Industrey: </label>
 <Select>
  .....
  <option>Other</option>
  </select>
  </td>
  <?php
   if($IndustryType == "Other")
    echo '<div id="Other">
  <td>
 <label for="=Other" class="collapse">Other: </label><input id="Other" name="Other"       class="collapse"/>
  </div>
  <br/>
 <br/>
 </td>
   ?>
 </tr>
  <br/>
<br/>
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <tr>
 <th><p><b>What interests you, broadly speaking?</b></p></th>
 </tr>
 <tr><td>
 <input type="checkbox">Web Design/Development</input>
 </td></tr>
 <tr><td>
 <input type="checkbox">Social Media</input>
 </td></tr>
 <tr><td>
 <input type="checkbox">Mobile Presence</input>
 </td></tr>
 <tr><td>
 <input type="checkbox">Online Advertising</input>
 </td></tr>
 <tr><td>
 <input type="checkbox">Search Engine Optamization</input>
 </td></tr>
 <tr><td>
 <input type="checkbox">eCommerce</input>
 </td></td>
 <tr>
 <th><div class="spacer"></div></th>
 </tr>
 <tr><td>
 <label for="comments"><b>Your Ideas to Life? (How can we help you?)</b></label><br/>
 <textarea id="comments" name="comments" style="margin: 2px; height: 137px; width:  437px;"></textarea></td></tr><br/>
 <tr>
 <td><input type="button" name="Submit" value="Submit" align="middle" /></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 </form>
```

I have tried putting the email function in a separate file called mail.php but that didn't work so i inline it into the HTML and the page fails on load.

I was also unsuccesfull in getting XAMPP to work locally as well.

I know its something could even be something small, but i am hoping to figure out what it is and learning in the process.
Any docs or web sites you prefer to aid me would be awesome as well.

any help is appreciated!

Comment: It doesn't appear `echo '<div id="Other">` actually ends..

Comment: <?php
   if($IndustryType == "Other")
    echo '<div id="Other">
  <td>
 <label for="=Other" class="collapse">Other: </label><input id="Other" name="Other"       class="collapse"/>
  </div>
  <br/>
 <br/>
 </td>
   ?>

Comment: `onSubmit="return    evalid()"` is this function defined in javascript, else try removing it

Comment: @sabithpocker it is in javascript

Comment: Don't you need to end the `'` before `?>` - Sorry, my PHP is rusty.

Comment: These questions ending up in "doesn't work" ... "failed to ..." are just as if you go to the doctor telling him "I'm feeling ill" and he knows exactly which prescription is the best in exactly your sickness. Without any more information, what do you expect what we shoukd do other than recommend to RTFM ?

Comment: It would *really* help if you actually said what the error was and how it's not working.  I don't think anyone really feels like debugging this whole thing line by line.

Comment: Try changing `mail($Email, $subject, $formcontent);` to  `mail($Email, $subject, $formcontent, $mailHeader);` And that `echo '<p class="collapse">Thank you...` doesn't seem right to me, seems out of place for some reason. Try setting it below your `mail($Email...`. As well as your `echo 'Please Check required fields...` needs a `'` at the end.

Comment: (addendum) your `echo 'Please Check required fields...` needs a `';` at the end.

Comment: Another thing. Since you say that you inlined the action form, remove `action="mail.php"` and try changing it to `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use the library phpmailer to send emails. You can find some tutorials about how use it

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up SMTP in your `php.ini` file. If you don't know what to set the SMTP as, then do a Google search for your email carrier's SMTP. Also set the port.

Your SMTP and port should be set according to your email carrier. So if you use [Gmail](http://email.about.com/od/accessinggmail/f/Gmail_SMTP_Settings.htm), than set these settings like this:

```
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 25
```

Your form's action attribute is set to `action="mail.php`. Make sure that your code is in that file. Finally, restart apache. If you are still receiving errors then try this:

```
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' . $youremail. "\r\n";
mail($Email, $subject, $formcontent);
```

**Note**: the `$youremail` variable is the email address you use and the email address that you set you SMTP settings for.

**Final steps**: Go [here](http://glob.com.au/sendmail/) and download the sendmail package and extract it in your xampp root directory. Edit these lines:

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=25
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=yourname@gmail.com
auth_password=gmailpassword
force_sender=yourname@gmail.com
```

Next open the xampp php.ini file again and edit the line that says `sendmail_path`. Make sure it is not commented.

```
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

**Restart apache.**

Comment: i have tried it live as well and still wont send email. Not just through XAMPP, as well all my code is in mail.php should it be separate from the contact.html?

Comment: Put the code in the file `mail.php` and make sure that file is in the same directory as your html form file. Next, take a deep breath, stay on xampp, you're fine. To send mail like that you need to set your smtp in your `php.ini` file. Take a look at my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is returning this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /var/www/crm.demotores.6.5.11/site/test.php on line 5
```

You should change in your php.ini - `display_errors = On` to see what's going on with your script.

The ")" was missed in this line. After fix it, you have:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''<div id="Other">' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE) in /var/www/crm.demotores.6.5.11/site/test.php on line 72
```